# При нажатии на div или ссылку изменить переменную

Tags: php, javascript

Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на `div` или ссылку изменилась переменная `php` или `js` без разницы. Есть код:

```
                <a href="">
                    <div class="f1">
                        <img src="/images/main3.jpg" alt="текст">                           
                    </div>
                </a>
```

И вот при клике на эту ссылку, ну или `div`, в принципе, это выглядит как одно целое, поэтому не знаю что реагирует на клик. Так вот, необходимо изменить переменную, предположим, `d`, которая изначально равна "1", а при нажатии должна измениться на "2". Повторюсь, что переменная может быть как `php`, так и `js`, не важно.

Подскажите пожалуйста. Благодарю!

Comment: "переменная может быть как php, так и js, не важно" - еще как важно!

Comment: "переменная php", вы вообще понимаете javascript?

Comment: в моем случае не так важно, а важно решить лишь проблему. Если она решается только для переменной php - отлично, сойдет. Если только для JS, тоже супер.

Comment: php это название переменной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
d = 1;
console.log(d);

document.querySelector('.f1').onclick = function() {
  d = 2;
  console.log(d);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="f1">
    <img src="/images/main3.jpg" alt="текст">
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59912/discussion-on-answer-by-alex78191----div----).